# Does SQL Server jump leaves when using a composite clustered index?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, clustered-index

Consider the following composite clustered index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_mytable ON mytable(a, b)
```

Obviously, a separate index on *b* will make searching for a particular value of *b* faster.

However, if a separate index on *b* is **not** employed, it seems to me that the composite index can still be used to find tuples with a particular value for *b* instead of a table scan, by traversing the tree of discrete values of *a* and do a local search for *b*, jump to the next value of *a*, etc.

Is this how SQL Server works? (It would not be, for instance, if MSSQL uses a single hash value for indexes with multiple columns.)

It it is, and the composite index is needed already for other reasons, and the number of discrete values of *a* is small enough, the performance/space trade-off may swing away from having a separate index for *b*.

(The UNIQUE and CLUSTERED constraints above aren't really required for this example, but they would represent the fastest retrieval of *b* that did not involve a separate index for *b*--the former providing a shortcut for each loop of *a*, the latter removing one degree of indirection in the lookup).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no jumping over a clusters of 'a'. An index can be used only if the leftmost column is specified, otherwise a full scan needs to be employed.

Oracle has the so called ['Index Skip Scan'](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/oracle9i/daily/apr22.html) operator.

Comment: "Index Skip Scan" is exactly the sort of method I was envisioning. A bit disappointed that MSSQL doesn't do this when it can, since it tends to be a more OOTB-friendly RDBMS than Oracle.

Comment: Here is the corresponding Microsoft Connect item: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/695044/implement-index-skip-scan Please vote for it.

Comment: @usr - Just read your Connect Item and followed your link back to Stack Overflow. It is possible to do a poor man's version of this using a recursive CTE. [Example syntax here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753319/sql-server-pick-random-or-first-value-with-aggregation/7753492#7753492)

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thanks, I already stumbled upon this. This solution doesn't work with OR-Mappers because of the CTR. I try to convince Microsoft to add this feature because it would be so convenient if they did. Magically, some query would be running a lot faster without the developer doing anything.

Comment: @usr - And the recursive CTE approach (repeated index seeks) is a lot less efficient than a true skip scan would be and probably needs many rows per group to make its use worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
-- Source: http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/59211
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SalesOrderHeader_OrderDate_#_ShipDate_SubTotal
ON [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] ([OrderDate])
INCLUDE (ShipDate,SubTotal)
-- WITH(DROP_EXISTING=ON);
GO

-- Test 1
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader h -- Index Seek on IX_SalesOrderHeader_OrderDate_#_ShipDate_SubTotal
WHERE   h.OrderDate BETWEEN '2008-07-01T00:00:00.000' AND '2008-07-15T23:59:59.997';
SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
GO
-- End of Test 1
-- Results:
-- Table 'SalesOrderHeader'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5, physical reads 0

DROP INDEX IX_SalesOrderHeader_OrderDate_#_ShipDate_SubTotal
ON [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SalesOrderHeader_ShipMethodID_OrderDate_#_ShipDate_SubTotal] 
ON Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
(
    ShipMethodID ASC,
    OrderDate ASC
)
INCLUDE (ShipDate,SubTotal);
GO

-- Test 2
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader h -- Index Scan on IX_SalesOrderHeader_ShipMethodID_OrderDate_#_ShipDate_SubTotal
WHERE   h.OrderDate BETWEEN '2008-07-01T00:00:00.000' AND '2008-07-15T23:59:59.997';
SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
GO
-- End of Test 2
-- Results:
-- Table 'SalesOrderHeader'. Scan count 1, logical reads 150, physical reads 0

-- Test 3
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    Purchasing.ShipMethod sm
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader h ON h.ShipMethodID=sm.ShipMethodID -- FK elimination + Index Scan on IX_SalesOrderHeader_ShipMethodID_OrderDate_#_ShipDate_SubTotal
WHERE   h.OrderDate BETWEEN '2008-07-01T00:00:00.000' AND '2008-07-15T23:59:59.997';
SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
GO
-- End of Test 3
-- Results:
-- Table 'SalesOrderHeader'. Scan count 1, logical reads 150, physical reads 0

-- Test 4
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SELECT  MIN(sm.ShipMethodID) AS DummnyCol, -- To prevent FK elimination 
        COUNT(*)
FROM    Purchasing.ShipMethod sm
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader h ON h.ShipMethodID=sm.ShipMethodID -- Index Seek on IX_SalesOrderHeader_ShipMethodID_OrderDate_#_ShipDate_SubTotal
WHERE   h.OrderDate BETWEEN '2008-07-01T00:00:00.000' AND '2008-07-15T23:59:59.997';
SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
GO
-- End of Test 4
-- Results:
-- Table 'SalesOrderHeader'. Scan count 5, logical reads 13, physical reads 0
-- Table 'ShipMethod'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0

DROP INDEX [IX_SalesOrderHeader_ShipMethodID_OrderDate_#_ShipDate_SubTotal] 
ON Sales.SalesOrderHeader;
GO
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
GO
```