# how to select unique records from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, distinct-values

Stored procedure is

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_ProductsByCategoryId_Filter]
 @CategoryId int,
 @BrandId int,
     @PageSize int,
       @PageIndex int

 AS
        SET NOCOUNT ON

 DECLARE @ParamDefinition AS NVARCHAR(2000) 

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)

SET @sql =     'select  DISTINCT   ProductId,  Name, Description,ProductPriceId,Price,Size,Weight,ThumbnailFilename,BrandId,DeliveryId,CategoryId,HasFreeWrapping,IsPharmaceutical,BrandCategoryId,Enabled,OpenForOffer,FreeDeliveryInUK,Discontinued,EnforceStockCount,OnlyInUK,ShowPreOrderButton,MinPrice
                from (SELECT   P.[ProductId], P.[Name], P.[Description],PP.[ProductPriceId],PP.[Price],PP.[Size],PP.[Weight], M.[ThumbnailFilename],M.[MEDIAFILENAME], P.[BrandId], P.[DeliveryId], P.[CategoryId], P.[HasFreeWrapping], P.[IsPharmaceutical], P.[BrandCategoryId], P.[Enabled], P.[OpenForOffer], P.[FreeDeliveryInUK], 
                               P.[Discontinued], P.[EnforceStockCount], P.[OnlyInUK], P.[ShowPreOrderButton], MIN(ISNULL(PP.[Price], 0)) AS [MinPrice],
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By  P.ProductId asc) AS 
                                RowRank 
                         FROM [Products] P  WITH (NOLOCK)
                        LEFT JOIN [ProductPrices] PP  WITH (NOLOCK) ON PP.[ProductId] = P.[ProductId]
                        INNER JOIN [ProductCategory] PC  WITH (NOLOCK) ON   P.[ProductId] =   PC.[ProductId]
                        INNER JOIN [Categories] C  WITH (NOLOCK) ON C.[CategoryId] = PC.[CategoryId] 
                        inner join [Brands] b  WITH (NOLOCK) ON  P.[brandid]= b.[brandid]
                        inner join [ProductMedia] m with (NOLOCK) ON P.[PRODUCTID]= M.[PRODUCTID]
                     WHERE 1 = 1 AND P.Enabled = 1 AND P.Discontinued = 0 AND PP.Stock > 0 AND (C.[CATEGORYID]=@CategoryId or  @CategoryId=0)   AND (P.[BRANDID]=@BrandId or @BrandId is null)
                     AND M.PRODUCTMEDIAID = (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 PRODUCTMEDIAID FROM PRODUCTMEDIA WHERE PRODUCTMEDIA.PRODUCTID=  P.PRODUCTID)
 GROUP BY P.[ProductId], P.[Name], P.[Description],PP.[ProductPriceId],PP.[Price],PP.[Size],PP.[Weight], M.[ThumbnailFilename],M.[MEDIAFILENAME], P.[BrandId],B.[BrandId], P.[DeliveryId], P.[CategoryId], P.[HasFreeWrapping], P.[IsPharmaceutical], P.[BrandCategoryId], P.[Enabled], P.[OpenForOffer], P.[FreeDeliveryInUK], P.[Discontinued], P.[EnforceStockCount], P.[OnlyInUK], P.[ShowPreOrderButton]
                    ) AS ProductsWithRowNumbers
            WHERE

            RowRank > ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @PageIndex ) +
                ' AND RowRank <= (' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), 
@PageIndex) + ' + '
                + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @PageSize) + ') '


              SET @ParamDefinition = '@CategoryId int,@BrandId int, @PageSize int,
    @PageIndex int
   '


-- Execute the SQL query

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @ParamDefinition,                        
                         @CategoryId,
                         @BrandId,
                          @PageSize ,
                                                    @PageIndex 


-- 

GO
```

in  the result of the above stored procedure, I get duplicate records, but I don't want to show duplicate records, please help me how can I get that

Comment: WHY on earth are you using dynamic SQL here?? There's absolutely no need for that......

Comment: according to application requirements i need than, can  u please help  me to get unique records(without duplicate records) from this@marc_s

Comment: i used the distinct  at the product id but still i got the duplicate records, please help me to solve this @marc_s

Comment: what is duplicate here?

Comment: product id,name and productdescription has the same values but other columns like priceid,price......are different,but i want to show unique records based on productid column please help me@vasin1987

Answer (score 0):

While you use DISTINCT, it seems duplicates you're getting is not real duplicates. Probably, repeating data still contain different values.

Update: while you need unique ProductId and want to pick any from non-unique data (different records corresponding to one ProductId), you need to use GROUP BY on ProductId and some other aggregate functions like MAX on all other fields like this:

```
SELECT ProductId, MAX(Name), MAX(Description)...
GROUP BY ProductId
```

If you really need functionality of FIRST/ANY aggregate (SQL Server lacks these aggregates), try CROSS APPLY trick like here: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=60565&whichpage=2#721589 or CTE trick like here: [SQL Server pick random (or first) value with aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753319/sql-server-pick-random-or-first-value-with-aggregation) or, if you using SQL Server 2012+, try [FIRST_VALUE analytic function](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh213018.aspx)

Comment: i want records uniquely based on productid only @Dmitry llukhin  my

Comment: some other columns having different values,but i want unique records based on productid only please help me@Dmitry llukhin

Comment: product id,name and productdescription has the same values but other columns like priceid,price......are different,but i want to show unique records based on productid column please help me@Dmitry llukhin

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but may clear up some things for someone who happens by.

First, you are not getting duplicate records if something in the row is different. when you execute a DISTINCT query, such as:

```
Select DISTINCT productID, salesID, name, time
FROM yourtable
```

Then SQL will find you distinct ROWS, not particular items from columns.

So, if ANY of the columns has disparate data, it will identify that row as distinct from others....this may seem like you are getting duplicates but alas, it is not the case.

If you wanted a list of distinct product IDs, then examine the code for your Stored Procdure and find where the Product ID's are coming from, in this case: [Products]

So if you want to get REALLY distinct then:

```
Select DISTINCT ProductID
FROM [Products]
```

Of course, I am being facetious as you don't need the DISTINCT in the code above...and you certainly wont derive the info you are looking for. sure you will want more amplifying information, so use SELECT * FROM Products to find out what columns from Products you want include and use them(AND ONLY THEM) in the distinct query of the stored procedure. That should give you distinct rows showing you what products are included in the query.

TaTa