# sql server multi column index queries

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing

If I have created a single index on two columns [lastName] and [firstName] in that order. If I then do a query to find the number of the people with first name daniel:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM people
WHERE firstName = N'daniel'
```

will this search in each section of the first index (lastname) and use the secondary index (firstName) to quickly search through each of the blocks of LastName entries?

This seems like an obvious thing to do and I assume that it is what happens but you know what they say about assumptions.

Comment: It may or it may not. Another index on `(firstName)` alone would be more efficient. Read this: [Displaying Graphical Execution Plans (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.105).aspx) for how to find out what happens.

Comment: Try looking at the query execution plan for an answer. Without knowing the schema and other indexes, this cannot be answered with certainty. However, the execution plan would show you what really happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does SQL Server jump leaves when using a composite clustered index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615893/does-sql-server-jump-leaves-when-using-a-composite-clustered-index)

Comment: It is an exact duplicate of that question, my apologise, and thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this query may - and probably do - use this index (and do an **Index Scan**) if the query optimizer thinks that it's better to *"quickly search through each of the blocks of LastName entries"* as you say than (do an **Full Scan**) of the table.

An index on `(firstName)` would be more efficient though for this particular query so if there is such an index, SQL-Server will use that one (and do an **Index Seek**).

---

Tested in SQL-Server 2008 R2, Express edition:

```
CREATE TABLE Test.dbo.people
( lastName  NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
, firstName NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
) ;

INSERT INTO people 
VALUES
('Johnes', 'Alex'),
...                   --- about 300 rows
('Johnes', 'Bill'),
('Brown', 'Bill') ;
```

---

Query without any index, **Table Scan**:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM people
WHERE firstName = N'Bill' ;
```

[image]

---

Query with index on `(lastName, firstName)`, **Index Scan**:

```
CREATE INDEX last_first_idx
ON people (lastName, firstName) ;

SELECT ...
```

### [image]

Query with index on `(firstName)`, **Index Seek**:

```
CREATE INDEX first_idx
ON people (firstName) ;

SELECT ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have an index on (lastname, firstname), in this order, then a query like

```
WHERE firstname = 'daniel'
```

won't use the index, as long as you don't include the first column of the composite index (i.e. lastname) in the `WHERE` clause. To efficiently search for firstname only, you will need a separate index on that column.

If you frequently search on both columns, do 2 separate single column indexes. But keep in mind that each index will be updated on insert/update, so affecting performance.

Also, avoid composite indexes if they aren't covering indexes at the same time. For tips regarding composite indexes see the following article at sql-server-performance.com:

[Tips on Optimizing SQL Server Composite Indexes](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/composite-indexes/)

**Update** (to address downvoters):

In this specific case of `SELECT Count(*)` the index is a covering index (as pointed out by @ypercube in the comment), so the optimizer may choose it for execution. Using the index in this case means an `Index Scan` and not an `Index Seek`.

Doing an `Index Scan` means scanning every single row in the index. This will be faster, if the index contains less rows than the whole table. So, if you got a highly selective index (with many unique values) you'll get an index with roughly as many rows as the table itself. In such a case usually there won't be a big difference in doing a `Clustered Index Scan` (implies a PK on the table, iterates over the PK) or a `Non-Clustered Index Scan` (iterates over the index). A `Table Scan` (as seen in the screenshot of @ypercube's answer) means that there is no PK on the table, which results in an even slower execution than a `Clustered Index Scan`, as it doesn't have the advantage of sequential data alignment on disk given by a PK.

Comment: Have you read the link you added? It says: *"Even if the WHERE clause in a query does not specify the first column of an available index (which normally disqualifies the index from being used), if the index is a composite index and contains all of the columns referenced in the query, the query optimizer can still use the index, because the index is a covering index."* And this index is covering for this query, as it contains all columns, e.g the one `lastName`, that is referenced in the query.

Comment: Have you read the link he added? :) It says: "A composite index is generally only useful to a query if the WHERE clause of the query matches the column(s) that are leftmost in the index. So if you create a composite index, such as “City, State”, then a query such as “WHERE City = ‘Springfield’” will use the index, but the query “WHERE STATE = ‘MO’” will not use the index."